# Jquery wrapAllInner() ? -- Or wrapAll() applied internally?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert an opening `<div class="container">` after `<body>` and a closing `</div>` before `</body>`

I'd like for there to be a function like `wrapAll()` that would apply internally, on the `html()` of an element. Something like `wrapAllInner()` would be great.

I've tried:

**1)** `$('body').html().wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>');`

which didn't work at all. *$("body").html().wrapAll is not a function*. weird.

**2)** `$('body').children().wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>');`

which for some reason caused the js to get repeated twice.  It even caused an alert() I placed right after it to get repeated twice. whut?

Thanks so much,

long time listener, first time caller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) to wrap the contents of the single `<body>` element works here, like this:

```
$('body').wrapInner('<div class="container"></div>');
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/m35Vq/).

---

The reason [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) doesn't work is [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) *without* parameters *gets* the HTML inside the `<body>` element, a string, which doesn't have any jQuery functions.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can't believe I missed that function.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could insert your div at the start of the body, then loop through the direct children in the body and move them inside the div:

```
$('body').prepend('<div class="container"></div>') ;
$('body').children().each() function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('container')) {
        $(this).prependTo('div.container') ;
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: There's no need for all this moving around, `.wrapInner()` does exactly what the OPs after here.